# Search for a string and return its value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a text column where the data is being automatically populated from a machine. Below is the data format which is being populated at the database. The format of the data is almost same for all records which I have in this table.

```
==========================
=== S U P E R  S O N Y ===
========================
START AT 12:16:29A
           ON 02-18-19
                        
MACHINE COUNT   1051
OPERATOR ______________

SERIAL # 0777218-15
                        
                  V=inHg
- TIME       T=F  P=psig
------------------------
D 12:16:31A 104.6   0.0P
D 12:16:41A 104.1   0.0P
D 12:26:41A 167.2  28.7V
D 12:31:41A 108.1  28.5V
MACHINE VALUE IS:       
1.5 mg/min
L 12:41:41A  95.1  28.4V
L 12:43:54A  97.2   1.9V
Z 12:45:23A  97.5   0.0P
                                           
========================
=    CHECK    COMPLETE  =
========================
```

I need to find the exact value after the "MACHINE VALUE IS:" and before "mg/min" word. In the above case, the query must return "1.5". The query I have written is failing because of some spaces after "MACHINE VALUE IS:" word.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(contents,
                LOCATE('IS:', contents), 10),'IS:', ''),'mg','') as value from machine_content
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(contents, 'IS:', -1), 'mg', 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the number behind `IS:<br>` of yourse, uin your case you must change, to what ever breaks the line like `cr lf`

> ```
> SET @sql := '==========================
> === S U P E R  S O N Y ===
> ========================
> START AT 12:16:29A
>            ON 02-18-19
>                         
> MACHINE COUNT   1051
> OPERATOR ______________
>
> SERIAL # 0777218-15
>                         
>                   V=inHg
> - TIME       T=F  P=psig
> ------------------------
> D 12:16:31A 104.6   0.0P
> D 12:16:41A 104.1   0.0P
> D 12:26:41A 167.2  28.7V
> D 12:31:41A 108.1  28.5V
> MACHINE VALUE IS:       
> 1.5 mg/min
> L 12:41:41A  95.1  28.4V
> L 12:43:54A  97.2   1.9V
> Z 12:45:23A  97.5   0.0P
>                                            
> ========================
> =    CHECK    COMPLETE  =
> ========================
> '
> ```

> ```
> SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@sql, 'IS:', -1), 'mg', 1),'\n','')
> ```
>
> ```
> | REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@sql, 'IS:', -1), 'mg', 1),'\n','') |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |        1.5                                                                  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f1092a3ab4cadf54243a04f10422530)*